# Cant Deploy Symfony app to Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I keep trying to deploy my symfony2 app to Heroku and i keep running into these errors. I have been working on this all week. Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I will include some important files. Let me know if you need me to include anything else. Thanks!

These 4 errors in particular:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or
>   directory
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                  SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory
>
> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
>   handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
            "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
            "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
            "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
            "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
}
```

This is my appKernel.php file

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{

public function __construct($environment, $debug){
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Chicago' );
parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
                    new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
                    new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Foodoo\Bundle\FoodooBundle\FoodooFoodooBundle(),
        new Blogger\BlogBundle\BloggerBlogBundle(),
                    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
                    new Blogger\UserBundle\BloggerUserBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

This is my config.yml file:

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: @BloggerBlogBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }

framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        [BloggerBlogBundle]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
encryption: ssl
# spool:     { type: memory }

# configuration for fos user bundle
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: demo_fos_login
user_class: Blogger\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

And this is the error log from heroku:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Resolved composer.lock requirement for PHP to version 5.6.4.
-----> Installing system packages...
   - PHP 5.6.4
   - Apache 2.4.10
   - Nginx 1.6.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
   - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled)
-----> Installing dependencies...
   Composer version 1.0.0-alpha9 2014-12-07 17:15:20
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Installing dependencies from lock file
     - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 80%      Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.3)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing twig/twig (v1.16.3)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.3.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.6.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (v1.0.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (v1.0.1)
       Cloning e4b6f810aa047f9cbfe41c3d6a3d7e83d7477a9d

     - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download jdorn/sql-formatter from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
       Cloning 64990d96e0959dff8e059dfcdc1af130728d92bc

     - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/dbal from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.0)
       Cloning 71140662c0a954602e81271667b6e03d9f53ea34

       Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine-dbal for package doctrine/dbal: name conflicts with an existing file
     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.3.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/doctrine-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.3.0)
       Cloning 3beb3a780485ab01f86941f4892cd23ef8c39c6b

     - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (v1.0.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/data-fixtures from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (v1.0.0)
       Cloning b4a135c7db56ecc4602b54a2184368f440cac33e

     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (v2.2.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (v2.2.0)
       Cloning c811f96f0cf83b997e3a3ed037cac729bbe3e803

     - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master 96f838b)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/migrations from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master 96f838b)
       Cloning 96f838b4fa93693d19196c8e24ed5f1c3972ba87

     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (dev-master 81575a4)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (dev-master 81575a4)
       Cloning 81575a4316951125ce408c70f30547c77d98f78a

     - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.7)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download doctrine/orm from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.7)
       Cloning 2bc4ff3cab2ae297bcd05f2e619d42e6a7ca9e68

       Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
       Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine.php for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
     - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v1.3.5)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download friendsofsymfony/user-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v1.3.5)
       Cloning d66890ad3489e18be153502c5ccc3f2bf5cce442

     - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download incenteev/composer-parameter-handler from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.0)
       Cloning 143272a0a09c62616a3c8011fc165a10c6b35241

     - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download ircmaxell/password-compat from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
       Cloning 5c5cde8822a69545767f7c7f3058cb15ff84614c

     - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v2.0.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download sensiolabs/security-checker from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v2.0.0)
       Cloning 5b4eb4743ebe68276c911c84101ecdf4a9ae76ee

       Skipped installation of bin security-checker for package sensiolabs/security-checker: name conflicts with an existing file
     - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.14)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download sensio/distribution-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.14)
       Cloning dc20d5ab3251587b047859ca2fc06c1b88a38d00

     - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.4)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download sensio/framework-extra-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.4)
       Cloning b3bc3e67c8b6b68b18d727012183520d35ee762a

     - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.2.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download kriswallsmith/assetic from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.2.1)
       Cloning b20efe38845d20458702f97f3ff625d80805897b

     - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.5.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download symfony/assetic-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.5.0)
       Cloning 90ea7fb66d6d5245fd4afc16e4c8070214254fec

     - Installing monolog/monolog (1.12.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download monolog/monolog from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing monolog/monolog (1.12.0)
       Cloning 1fbe8c2641f2b163addf49cc5e18f144bec6b19f

     - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.7.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download symfony/monolog-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.7.0)
       Cloning e8f71c91a3784f3fa1a75fb1f7f4d4826c5f2773

     - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download swiftmailer/swiftmailer from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.1)
       Cloning c5f963e7f9d6f6438fda4f22d5cc2db296ec621a

     - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.8)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download symfony/swiftmailer-bundle from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.8)
       Cloning 970b13d01871207e81d17b17ddda025e7e21e797

     - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Failed to download twig/extensions from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
       Now trying to download from source
     - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
       Cloning 8cf4b9fe04077bd54fc73f4fde83347040c3b8cd

   Generating optimized autoload files
   Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
   Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false



     [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                     
     An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  






     [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]               
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  






     [PDOException]                                    
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets   
handling  the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception       

[RuntimeException]                                                            
An error occurred when executing the "'assets:install '\''web'\'''" command.  

!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you didn't add the cleardb addon to your heroku instance

```
 heroku addons:add cleardb:ignite
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did to fix this issue:

My `config_prod.yml` file imported my `config.yml` file which imported the `parameters.yml` file which included my database configuration info for my local server.

When you upload it to the live server (heroku, or any other server) you need to have that `parameters.yml` file configured for the new database.

**Option 1 (easy fix):** 
You can either change your database config in your parameters.yml file to match the `cleardb:ignite` database for heroku. but then it won't work on your local server unless you change the database config info back.

**Option 2:** 
You can create another `parameters.yml` file and name it something different. i.e `production_parmaeters.yml`, and import that file in your `config_prod.yml` file. and make sure your c`onfig_dev.yml` file includes your original `parameters.yml` file which has your local development database config in it.

Then delete the

```
- { resource: parameters.yml }
```

in your main `config.yml` file.

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just search for the "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" message on Google, you'll quickly find an explanation: a connection to MySQL through a Unix domain socket failed because that socket, e.g. `/var/sock/mysql.sock`, does not exist (MySQL does that if you try to connect to `localhost`, while it uses a TCP/IP socket if you connect to `127.0.0.1`).

Your problem then, most likely, is that you have database credentials set up for the `prod` environment somewhere, but these credentials are invalid, as they try to connect to a `localhost` MySQL.